# reading odt files in php

Tags: php, opendocument

How would you go about reading odt files in PHP? I know you can use QueryPath, but that seems a bit of an overkill,.. I just want to read the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

odt, files are zip compressed xml.

If all you need to do is read the file raw. Just unzip it and read it like a normal file.

If you need to parse out usable text, then enters the need for QueryPath or some other xslt parser.

Comment: I have no idea how I'm going to code that.. use zip_open, then zip_read,.. then file_get_contents?

Comment: Here is a great little article doing the whole thing in 10 lines of code. http://technosophos.com/content/reading-odt-files-querypath

Comment: Arr,... all I need to do was change some file permissions, nothing wrong with that, sorry

Answer (score 2):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is able to read and modify OpenDocument files in PHP.

Since OpenDocument files are XML files stored into a zip archive, you can also use the [TbsZip](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/tools.php) class to simply read a zip archive under PHP without any other library dependency.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Name of the document file*/
$document = 'Template.odt';

/**Function to extract text*/
function extracttext($filename) {

    $dataFile = "content.xml";     

    //Create a new ZIP archive object
    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    // Open the archive file
    if (true === $zip->open($filename)) {
        // If successful, search for the data file in the archive
        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) {
            // Index found! Now read it to a string
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // Load XML from a string
            // Ignore errors and warnings
            $xml = new DOMDocument;
            $xml->loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
            // Return XML
            return $xml->saveXML();
        }
        //Close the archive file
        $zip->close();
    }   
    // In case of failure return a message
    return "File no`enter code here`t found";
}

echo extracttext($document);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.php.net/package/OpenDocument may be what you need. Haven't used it myself, though.