# Read a Word XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

Does anyone have any recommendations for how to read a Word (2007-2013) file using PHP?  I'm using the build in styles to mark up a word document, and would like to read it with PHP ideally in order to analyze the contents.  I've tried searching google and this site, but no luck.  If anyone has any experience with this or ideas on where I would get started, it would be appreciated.

Comment: so is it a word file that you place xml inside of?

Comment: @Bot - Word 2007-1013 use XML as the native file format.... a word file __is__ an xml file

Comment: @Bot. I doubt it. Recent MSWord files (`.docx`) store data in compressed XML format.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just interested in the content of the Word Document and for example turning it into an HTML page. I would not recommend PHPWord as its internal structure is quite complex. The following code uses only PHP native functionalities to read all Paragraphs of an docx Document.

```
 /*DOCX is actually a ZIP file containing other files, document.xml 
holds the text of you document, sadly not the styles, you need to drill
further into other files to extract the styles*/

    $result = file_get_contents('zip://word.docx#word/document.xml');

    //Load the document XML into PHP's SimpleXML
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result,null, 0, 'w', true);
    $body = $xml->body;
    foreach($body[0] as $key => $value){
        echo "<p>";
        if($key == "p"){
            foreach ($value->r as $kkey => $vvalue) {
                echo (string)$vvalue->t;
            }
        }
        echo "</p>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("MyFile.docx");
if (($index = $zip->locateName("word/document.xml")) !== false) {
    $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
    $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
    echo $xml->saveXML();
}
$zip->close();
```

if you need to install the zip ext you can find it here: http://php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php

hope it helps you along!

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPWord! I believe that has a function to read docs.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not quite what you were looking for, but could you get them to re-save the Word documents in .odt?

This article could help if you get to that stage:
[reading odt files in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069852/reading-odt-files-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer, but my preference is to break a complex problem like this into simpler pieces.

The approach I would use is to open it in Word (or in OpenOffice or LibreOffice) and save as HTML. Then I would prepend a  instruction and read it with one of the many XML classes/extensions available in PHP.

[I found this question because I was Googling for a framework that would let me go through the HTML that Word generates and clean it up -- turn it into legal XHTML1.0, remove the useless style information that Word creates, while preserving my user-generated styles, etc. That second will require some experimentation to determine what I want to keep and what I want to discard, but I think that is well within my hobbyist capabilities.]